# Appending certain text on Hadoop Cascading Flow

Tags: hadoop, cascading

In Hadoop Cascading Flow, i have a number of tuples which is processed and finally i have sunk into a destination.

**Now my requirement is:** To sink that tuples in destination file with certain defined constant String values at beginning and at the end.

**For example:** I have following input tuples

```
10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20
20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10
```

Now i need to have like this output:

```
Certain data before those data
10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20
20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10
Certain data after those data
```

Little bit i have searched of repository class **DelimitedParser** and its methods like **joinLine**, **joinFirstLine** but due to poor documentation i am unable to get exact point of it.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what "Certain data before those data" means ?
If you are using [TextDelimited](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/javadoc/cascading/scheme/hadoop/TextDelimited.html), then you can dump the header values in the sink. By default header values are not written as per the documentation hence you will need to enable it. Another thing to remember is that the header values represents the output fields.

-Amit